# IIS php extension in URL

Tags: php, iis

I'm migrating an Apache server to an IIS server.

Currently, in the **Apache server**, if we have a PHP page named ***www.example.com/test.php***, we can access it even without the final ".php" (i.e. *www.example.com/test*).

How to achieve a similar behavior in IIS?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: IIS does have url rewrite module. You can download it from ms

Comment: Can you please give me a hint on how to configure my specific role?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you running?

Comment: The version of IIS is 8.5.9600.16384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IIS8 and above Microsoft implemented the Web Platforms and you can download the module URL Rewrite from there (or just download it from [their site](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)).

After that, go to the IIS Service Management and click on "URL Rewrite"

[image: URL Rewrite on IIS 8]

At the right panel, you'll see a option to "Import rules.."

[image: Import htaccess rules into IIS]

Choose your `.htaccess` (that you currently have on your `public_html`) and click on the "Import" button.

This creates a file called `web.config` in the path of your site with a content that will look like the follwing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="index\.php/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There are also some online services that may convert your `.htaccess` to `web.config` although I've tried a few and the import from the IIS Service Management works better.